# Can I use paster on production site?

Tags: apache, pylons, paster

I am trying to set up [Mediacore](http://getmediacore.com/docs/) (which is a Pylons app) on a production server. The docs suggest either apache mod_fastcgi or mod_wsgi as webserver but I try to avoid apache at any cost because of its being RAM-monger. On the other hand mediacore works just fine when I use it with paster, so I am wondering what are pros/cons of just ignoring apache and use paster as my production web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your load grows, you may hit the CPU or DB limit. The typical answer is using several parallel backends. Then an nginx or lighttpd or whatever light HTTP server will come in handy and will allow you to distribute load to several paster servers and serve static files cheaply.

Up until then you're probably safe to run just paster, especially if you have excess CPU to waste on serving static files.

Comment: Thanks 9000. Is there any particular non-apache that you suggest for the web server? I've seen good benchmarks from nginx+uwsgi but it is rather new and lacks noob-friendly docs.

Comment: I'm not an expert either. People around me keep using nginx. You may also be interested to read this: http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers It seems that you may get quite a boost by moving from paster to another Python WSGI server.