# Running CKAN behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, fastcgi, production, ckan

I would like to run CKAN behind Nginx. Does it make sense to run the CKAN site through the paster process:

```
paster serve production.ini
```

... and then just point Nginx at it through a reverse proxy?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

Or is there a way to run as a FastCGI process? Perhaps a FastCGI daemon process [similar to Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#examples)?

Answer (score 1):

The default installation of CKAN (the one done via [package install](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/install-from-package.html)) sets up CKAN running on Apache with mod_wsgi with Nginx on top. Have at look at the [Apache](https://github.com/okfn/ckan-packaging/blob/master/etc/apache2/sites-available/ckan_default) and [Nginx](https://github.com/okfn/ckan-packaging/blob/master/etc/nginx/sites-available/ckan) configuration files for details on how it is done.

Regarding using paster on a production environment, I'd imagine that sooner or later you will hit performance problems, so I would avoid it. You may find this answer useful:

[Can I use paster on production site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799908/can-i-use-paster-on-production-site)

Comment: Thanks -- but it looks to me like the Nginx config file shown there does exactly what I'm doing -- proxy traffic over to :8000, where I'd assume paster is running CKAN. The linked answer also seems to suggest the primary drain is in serving static files through paster. I suppose you could alter the Nginx config so that those files in CKAN are served directly, but CKAN doesn't have the same kind of static file collection that operates across plugins like Django does...

Comment: Just to clarify, port :8000 is running Apache, which should not have any problem serving static files.

Comment: Right -- I misunderstood. You're running CKAN through Apache, Nginx on top. I was hoping to find a way to flatten that down to just using Nginx